# Change handler for mailto: links

Tags: windows-7, browser, mailto

How can I setup Gmail or Hotmail as default mail handler, for example, in HTML, we use the following, which should open Gmail or Hotmail.

`<a href="mailto:support@example.com">Click here to mail us</a>`

Comment: This is all based on protocol, by default `mailto:` is assigned to Outlook (Desktop Mail Client).

Comment: Please specify your OS also!

Comment: Oh, im sorry. I'm on Windows 7 Professional. Is it possible to change the default mail client? If i configure Gmail for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It not *points* to anything `mailto:` links calls default mail application on user machine, just as `http:` calls default browser. [Here's how](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Getting-Gmail-to-handle-all-mailto-links-with-registerProtocolHandler) to set `mailto:` protocol handler to Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

`mailto:` can be set to be handled by Web Mail services like Gmail and Hotmail with [this little Program](http://gmaildefault.codeplex.com/).

**Note: The name say Gmail but this program is capable of setting these:**

1. Gmail
2. Google Apps
3. Yahoo
4. Hotmail
5. AOL
6. QQ Mail

Answer (score 0):

If you are the user who clicks on the links, you can use Google Notifier or have Chrome default to opening mailto links in Gmail.

http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10966

If you are a web developer, I strongly recommend using the mailto: protocol for compatibility, but if you were to target gmail users directly, you can do something like https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&source=mailto&to=support@example.com.